# Is it possible to 'split' the value of a set /p command in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is it possible in CMD to **partialy** extract the value of a string from the `set /p var=`command and assign each part to some other different variables? I mean, let's say that we used the `set /p var=` command to read some input from the user, and the user typed in *I am Joe* . So, now the variable `%var%="I am Joe"` . Is it possible to assign the "I am" content of %var% to another variable and the "Joe" content to another one as well?

Answer (score 0):

It kind of all depends on what you can expect from the given input. You could use substrings to subtract a fixed part of the input string, like this:

```
:: part1 = I am
set "part1=%var:~0,4%"

:: part2 = Joe
set "part2=%var:~5,7%"
```

But if the length of the input string is less than 5, the variable **part2** will be undefined. As if you didn't give the variable any value.

```
:: Like this
set part2=
```

Another way to get parts of the input string is by tokenizing it. Like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in ("%var%") do (
  set "part1=%%a %%b"
  set "part2=%%c"
)
```

But there are a couple of problems with this approach that you should be aware of. First of all, since the input is provided by the user it could contain reserved shell characters in combination with doubles quotes and such that could actually break the code. Second, the number of tokens to use and how to deal with them has to be predefined.

Comment: Both options work perfect for me. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark your question as answered. :>